# How do I locate the question I previously asked?

Tags: discussion, story-identification

I am new to the site and I do not understand how to locate the question I asked yesterday.  Can anyone explain to me how I find my own question and any possible answers to it?

Please note that I am not sure that I will be able to locate THIS question, or any answers to it!!

Comment: Presumably, based on your confusion, you did not have the same user account before. Otherwise, you could click on your username to see. Otherwise, you can use the search bar if you remember the words you used, or you can scroll down the questions, listed by Newness, and scan for your question. Either way, I've flagged this to go to Meta.

Answer (score 11):

There's a few options available to you

- You can sort [questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) by newness. Presumably it's one of the questions asked yesterday
- You could use the [search facility](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=) to search for the title.
- You could search for it by [tag](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags) (our questions are usually very well curated).
- If you remember the username you used before, you can search [by username](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=newusers)
- If you've got enough rep (20 points) you could ask in the [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe)

---

For the record, I'm pretty sure this is your question.

**[Earth sends fleet to destroy an alien species that requires a virus to reach maturity](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/203263/earth-sends-fleet-to-destroy-an-alien-species-that-requires-a-virus-to-reach-mat)**

If you have created two accounts, you can ask for them to be merged by following the instructions on [this link](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). This way, you will be able to regain full ownership of the question, comment on it, reply to answerers, and accept an answer if there is a most satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest, assuming it is the same account:

- Click on your account, where the rep is, upper right corner.
- Click on the tab Questions.
- Sort by posting date.

Comment: In this instance, OP has created two accounts accidentally, hence why they can't see the question when they click on their account,

Comment: Yes: this would be the simplest answer in general, but it doesn't work in this particular case.